# LaTeX document alignment

Tags: ragged2e

In our document we tried to align everything with [`ragged2e`](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Text_alignment?fbclid=IwAR32jZIPOOoosoUyFXakiKihTZKyVYNZlT_JPZ2tjp-iDvaFB_fQ-mW0r_U) package and it doesn't really help to align as some of the text is align and some of it isn't.

I have added this command in master folder after preamble and after `\begin{document}` I wrote `\begin{FlushLeft}` and before `\end{document}` I wrote `\end{FlushLeft}`.

[image]

Furthermore the whole introduction is align correctly but then another chapter is included the gap starts to move from left to right

[image]

The bullet points are going one after each over.

[image]

The following is the code

```
\input{setup/preamble.tex}% package inclusion and set up of the document
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\input{setup/hyphenations.tex}% 
\input{setup/macros.tex}% my new macros
%\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{FlushLeft}
%frontmatter

\pagestyle{empty} %disable headers and footers
\pagenumbering{roman} %use roman page numbering in the frontmatter
\input{sections/frontpage.tex}
%%\input{sections/colophon.tex}
\input{sections/titlepages.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{label:contents}
\pagestyle{fancy} %enable headers and footers again
\tableofcontents
%\listoftodos
%\input{sections/preface.tex}
%\cleardoublepage
%mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic} %use arabic page numbering in the mainmatter
\input{sections/introduction.tex}
\input{sections/ch2contextPA.tex}
\input{sections/ch3techPA.tex}
\input{sections/ch4fpf.tex}
\input{sections/ch5.tex}
\input{sections/ch6.tex}
\input{sections/ch7implementation.tex}
\input{sections/ch8testing.tex}
\input{sections/ch9discussion.tex}
\input{sections/conclusion.tex}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\label{bib:mybiblio}
\appendix
\input{sections/appAname.tex}
\end{FlushLeft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably, that is because you are using `twoside` option (which is to print it in both sides). Use `oneside` in the class. Also, be careful when changing the margins.

Comment: @Sigure - You could read those screen shots?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Actually it is not difficult to read text in the screenshot. The difficult task is to paste that text to our editors for checking.

Comment: what do you mean by class? because i cant find it.

Comment: By "class" is is meant the line of code `\documentclass[...]{...}`, which defines the overall profile of the document.

Comment: Using a global `flushleft` environment is wrong; just issue `\raggedright` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: when we try to use \documentclass{oneside}  it says two \documentclass{} or \documentstyle{} commands but i can only find one.